# What is the proper way to call multiple XMLHttpRequests in the same/multiple script?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I think I ran into a problem of the same variable being used, I might have gotten lucky in some cases where they were separated by function scope. I recently replaced all of my jQuery code with plain JS and this broke a few things however the gained speed/lack of dependency(extra file to download) was good for me in this situation.

So I have the basic form of:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    url = "php/my-script.php",
    params = encodeURI('some-param='+value);
http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

http.onreadystatechange = function(data) {
  //Call a function when the state changes.
  if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
    var result = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
    if (result['status'] === "success") {
      someFunction(result['some_key']);
    }
  }
}
http.send(params);
```

When I ran into the problem of the same http variable being used, I started to replace new ones with http1, http2, etc... seems like a bad idea. Especially having to replace all the http-method(?) calls afterwards like http2.responseText, etc... Should I make this into a function... then pass in the values to post and return the data out?

I guess I don't understand what happens when you call:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Is that a one time use case, where after it has been called you need a new one for another post?

I will try the single-global-function approach. Everywhere I needed to do an AJAX call whether get or post, I always just used $.post/$.get on the spot, not sure if that's bad.

Comment: So wrap it so it is not a global variable.

Comment: @epascarello does that mean make it a function? That's what I intend to do I'm just concerned before I write all this code if it's a good idea.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. You should create a new XMLHttpRequest object for each call. Reusing it is not beneficial to you.

Comment: right now I keep copying/posting that block of code and changing the parts like the script, parameter, what to do after the call, so I think the answer is to make a global function with three parameters accessible by all scripts. I just ran into the problem of the http being "undefined" and I think it was because I had multiple blocks of that same code, not wrapped.

Comment: Well if you use the same variable in the same scope of course it will cause issues.

Comment: Alright I'll figure it out